# ElemMatch in MongoDb (C #, driver 2.0)

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to do a query to find records in which field (which is an array) contains a specified string:

```
var builder = Builders<ProductModelDb>.Filter;
var eqFilter = Builders<string>.Filter.Eq(x => x, "\nHome");
var matchFilter = builder.ElemMatch<string>(x=>x.productData.Breadcams, eqFilter);
var res = productCollection.Find(matchFilter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Data model:

```
public class ProductModelDb
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Url;
    public DateTime DateTime;
    public ProductDataModel productData;
}

public class ProductDataModel   
{        
    public List<string> Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Breadcams { get; set; }
}
```

When you start the program I receive this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldName
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[String] (System.String value, System.String paramName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.RenderedFieldDefinition`1[System.String]..ctor (System.String fieldName, IBsonSerializer`1 fieldSerializer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition`2[System.String,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.SimpleFilterDefinition`2[System.String,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.ElementMatchFilterDefinition`2[DataModels.ProductModelDb,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb].FindAsync[ProductModelDb] (MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition`1 filter, MongoDB.Driver.FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2[DataModels.ProductModelDb,DataModels.ProductModelDb].ToCursorAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__14`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb]].get_Result () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at DataBaseProcesser.CategoryProcessor.CreateCategory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at DataBaseProcesser.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--> (Inner exception 0) System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

What my error is? How to write queries ElemMatch?

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense. [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is used only if you match *multiple criteria* for each list item, e.g. when finding an element from the following `votes` where the user's name is john **and** he voted for Protoss.

```
{ 
   "_id" : "foo",
   "votes" : [ { "user" : "john", "for" : "Protoss" },
               { "user" : "mike", "for" : "Zerg" }, ... ]
}
```

For a list of non-objects, i.e. the list of strings in your example, you can simply use an eq query as if the field was no list in the first place. For example, on the console:

```
db.products.find({"productData.breadcams" : "Home"});
```

p.s.: do you mean [breadcrumbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29)?